# Updating a set of <select multiple> with JQuery chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a page with two set of `<select mutiple>` which has the JQuery chosen function attached to it.

When the user clicks on a checkbox, I need to

a) take a list of one of the two set of `select`

b) for each `select` read the selected options

c) mark as selected one of the actually unselected options

d) mark a unselected one of the actually selected options

The only part I made is "a)":

```
var regioni = document.getElementsByClassName('regioni');
```

In `regioni` I have the list of `select`, but now I have no idea how do the other parts.

Please ONLY solutions of plain javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Share your code...

Answer (score 0):

a) If you want a list of one of the selects you could do something like:

```
var arr_select = [];
$("#select_id option").each(function(i,e){arr_select.push($(e).val())});
```

b) If you want the values of each select:

```
var select_1_value = $("#select_1_id").val();
var select_2_value = $("#select_2_id").val();
```

But if you want the text of each element, you could try something like:

```
var select_1_text_selected = []; 
$("#select_id_1 option:selected").each(function(i,e){
   select_1_text_selected.push($(e).text())
});

var select_2_text_selected = []; 
$("#select_id_2 option:selected").each(function(i,e){
   select_2_text_selected.push($(e).text())
});
```

c) You need to give the property as selected to the option element, and then you need to refresh that chosen, you need to do something like:

```
$("#select_id option[value='1001']").prop('selected',true);
$("#select_id").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

'1001' is a value from an existing option element.

d) You could build the select with an empty option, and validate it later, and give a message to the user asking him for an option.

someting like this

```
<select id='select_1' class='chosen' data-placeholder='Please select something'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='1001'> phone</option>
</select>
```

So you can unselect something selected, with this:

```
$("#select_id option[value='']").prop('selected',true);
$("#select_id option[value='1001']").prop('selected',false);
$("#select_id").trigger('chosen:updated');
```